# Не работает скрипт с русскими символами

Tags: javascript

Есть функция:

```js
function translit() {
  var str = ge("search_input").value;
  var result = '';
  var space = "-";
  var transl = {
    'а': 'a',
    'б': 'b',
    'в': 'v',
    'г': 'g',
    'д': 'd',
    'е': 'e',
    'ё': 'e',
    'ж': 'zh',
    'з': 'z',
    'и': 'i',
    'й': 'j',
    'к': 'k',
    'л': 'l',
    'м': 'm',
    'н': 'n',
    'о': 'o',
    'п': 'p',
    'р': 'r',
    'с': 's',
    'т': 't',
    'у': 'u',
    'ф': 'f',
    'х': 'h',
    'ц': 'c',
    'ч': 'ch',
    'ш': 'sh',
    'щ': 'sh',
    'ъ': space,
    'ы': 'y',
    'ь': space,
    'э': 'e',
    'ю': 'yu',
    'я': 'ya'
  }
  if (str != '')
    str = str.toLowerCase();

  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (/[а-яё]/.test(str.charAt(i))) {
      result += transl[str.charAt(i)];
    } else if (/[a-z0-9]/.test(str.charAt(i))) {
      result += str.charAt(i);
    } else {
      if (result.slice(-1) !== space) result += space;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Если ее вставить в консоль, то при вызове `translit()` при `str=привет` результатом будет `privet`, но если функция будет находиться в файле, например, `main.js`, то результат функции будет `-`. При чем не работает только с русскими символами.

Почему это может происходить?

Comment: Видимо кодировка файла main.js отличается от кодировки в которой работает сайт.

Comment: @Visman, точно, проверил и, действительно, кодировки разные. Спасибо!